# jquery and visual studio and IE 8 not working

Tags: jquery

i have seen all the previous questions related to this but my problem is some what unique so this post.

I have very simple application

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/app1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app1.js look like this

> $(document).ready(function () {
>       alert("Test this app");
>       console.log("Test this app"); });

If i run the application from visualstudio in debuggin mode, i am not able to see the alert message in IE8 but the same code works fine in Firefox without any change in the code.

Not sure if i am missing something.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () { alert("Test this app");});
```

I suspect that IE8 is unable to deal with `console.log` so the whole statement fails, and the alert does not get displayed.

Comment: Hi, First all of all thanks for your very quick response. I tried what u have mentioned but no luck.

Comment: This fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/xXFqj/ works for me in IE 8. So the code should be working. Have you tried a CTRL+F5 to make sure IE isn't caching your js file?

Comment: I just tried ctrl+f5 it is not working, but when i run(double click) from the physical location the IE shows me the yellow bar with following warning message "To help your security IE has restricted this web page from running scripts or Active X controls ...", if allow that scripts to run i am able to see the alert message, but still if i press F5/run from VS not able to see alert message

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't have access to a 'console' object unless you have the developer tools open (F12). If you remove the console.log() part it should work.

Comment: I am using developer tools, i removed the console.log part but no luck. is there any other way to check whether my jquery dom ready event fired or not

Comment: Well, the best way to check would be to put an alert() or console.log() in it lol. Have you tried it in IE8 without using VS debugging mode?